# use a variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, variables, return, parameter-passing, declare

hello i have this function

```
locDistance(alat[i-1], alon[i-1], alat[i], alon[i]);

function locDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    //Radius of the earth in:  1.609344 miles,  6371 km  | var R = (6371 / 1.609344);
    //var R = 3958.7558657440545;
    var R = 3958.7558657440545; 
    var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1); 
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    var dist = d;
};

function toRad(Value) {
    /** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

i know i have to declare the variable outside the function to use it at another place 
so i have defined at the top of the page

```
var dist = 0;
```

i want to use de variable 'dist' in another function like in here

```
$('.content').append(dist);
```

but the problem is i keep getting 0 as result of the dist variable.

i have checked but inside de locDistance function the dist variable has different values as it should be so the function is not the issue here

what am i doing wrong?

thank you in advance

Comment: It would help if you at least tagged with the relevant programming language.

Comment: Try to avoid using global variables if you can avoid it. In this case, why not have `locaDistance` return the distance as a return value?

Comment: What @Barmar said... `return dist;` Should work just fine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that the code above does not work is that the var keyword is being used in the locDistance method, thereby setting dist to a local variable every time the function is called and leaving the global dist set to 0.

That being said...

Perhaps you would rather have locDistance return the value and then call the function when you need it, like:

```
$('.content').append(locDistance(alat[i-1], alon[i-1], alat[i], alon[i]));

function locDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
    //Radius of the earth in:  1.609344 miles,  6371 km  | var R = (6371 / 1.609344);
    //var R = 3958.7558657440545;
    var R = 3958.7558657440545; 
    var dLat = toRad(lat2-lat1);
    var dLon = toRad(lon2-lon1); 
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
            Math.cos(toRad(lat1)) * Math.cos(toRad(lat2)) * 
            Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
    var d = R * c;
    return d;
}

function toRad(Value) {
    /** Converts numeric degrees to radians */
    return Value * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: Ha I was modifying it to say just that, but thanks for the downvote.

Comment: The whole point of downvoting is to discourage bad code... I'll gladly remove it when you remove the offending code. :)

Comment: I didn't write the offending code - the original poster did - I simply answered his question as to why he was always seeing a 0 value. :)